# How is the idea of "Dahergelaufen" commonly expressed in Russian?

Tags: выражения, german

> Doch wir verteilen die nicht einfach an jeden **Dahergelaufenen**.

- *But they are too valuable for us to just dish out (**left and right**) to **anyone who happens to come along**.*

We were having a conversation in German, and I was wondering how I'd express the same idea in Russian.

The word "Dahergelaufen / dahergelaufen" -- used either as a substantive or adjective -- comes in handy to convey the negative connotation of "*doing something in a **random**, **haphazard** manner to just about **anyone who happens to come along***" -- as opposed to using the more neutral word "*irgendjemand* {*anybody*}".

Answer (score 3):

**первому встречному (-поперечному)

всем, кому ни пОпадя

всем, кому не лень**

> Они для нас слишком ценные, чтобы мы раздавали их `первому встречному
>   (-поперечному)` / `всем, кому ни пОпадя` / `всем, кому не лень`

Comment: Do you use any of them in this example, too: "*What are you guys chatting about?*" "*Sorry, we can't let just about **anybody** in on it.*"

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens here i would sound really rude, and 'sorry' wouldn't mitigate it enough, instead i'd say **Извини, но мы не можем всех посвящать в свои разговоры/дела | посвящать в свои разговоры/дела посторонних**

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens Раздавать\рассказывать и т.п можно **направо и налево**.